# How to count rows of finished BigQuery job using node.js client library

Tags: google-bigquery

I would like to get the row count of job that was run using:

```
bigquery.startQuery(options)
```

The naive way of doing this, would be to stream the result (e.g. using):

```
job.getQueryResultsStream()
```

And count one by one. This obviously isn't very efficient, especially for large results. Another way I thought of is using the metadata of the job:

```
job.on('complete', function(metadata) {...}
```

Where I could kind of "reverse engineer" the response, to get the query plan, and see the number of written rows in the last step. I could find that in:

```
statistics.query.queryPlan[statistics.query.queryPlan.length - 1].recordsWritten
```

While a sample of different queries convinced me that this might work, it  feels like a "hack", and it's difficult to say how robust it will be. Seems like I might need to handle different cases (failed queries, etc.)

EDIT: Another option suggested below is "SELECT COUNT"ing the temp table created by the original query (available in the job metadata). While this absolutely is a straightforward way to get the result I'm looking for, it has the disadvantage of requiring another roundtrip to query the BigQuery service, which costs several seconds. It is a 0 "bytes billed" query (counting a full table uses table metadata only), but it seems redundant when the job "knows" how many rows it has written to the output.

Is there a straightforward and "correct" way to get this count from the job object, without a roundtrip to BQ service? Perhaps a field I missed / misinterpreted, or a function in the job object that returns this?

Answer (score 3):

Any job has destination table - even when you do not explicitly set it - result is still saved in so-called anonymous table that you can in turn query to get the count of output rows. So below simple extra query will work (note - names are just as an example)

```
SELECT COUNT(1) 
FROM `yourProject._0511743a77ca76c1b55482d7cb1f8e91ac5c7b36.anon17286defe54b5c07ba6810a71abfdba6388ac4e0`
```

The actual destination table to use - can be retrieved from [configuration.query.destinationTable](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/reference/rest/v2/jobs#configuration.query.destinationTable) property of job

Comment: This would work correctly, but compared to peeking in the query plan, it has the disadvantage of requiring a roundtrip to the BQ service (which would cost a few seconds). I've edited the question to reflect this.

Comment: true. one more call. still an option that returns 100% correct result ! :o) consider vote if you liked it

Answer (score 1):

```
   job.on('complete', function(metadata) {
    console.log(metadata.statistics.query.numDmlAffectedRows)
   }
```

Comment: Can you please elaborate?